# Error Message: "Cannot convert type 'string?' to 'string' "

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

I have this code:

```
//Return null if the extension doesn't have the value, returns the value if it does.
private T? getValue<T>(IEnumerable<Extension> extension, string attributeName)
{
    IEnumerable<Extension> ext = extension.Where(e => e.attributeName == attributeName);
    if (ext.Count() > 0)
    {
        return (T)ext.First().Attribute;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm calling it like:

```
//This works:
retVal.byteValue= getValueFromExtension<byte>(u, "ByteToGet") ?? 0;
//This doesn't work:
getValueFromExtension<string>(u, "Text") ?? "";
```

I get the compile error: "Error Message: "Cannot convert type 'string?' to 'string' "

How can I do effectively the idea in the code above without creating a new method?

I feel like I'm checking if it's null with the ?? operator, so, if the string is null, it will always be set to an empty string. It is handled how I expect for byte and int, why not for string?

FYI, the byteValue above, is of type byte, not byte?.

Comment: Does this code compiles ever? I'm confused by `T?` return type of the method

Comment: What is `getValueFromExtension`?

Comment: I don't understand why your method even compiles without a `struct` constraint.

Comment: Why would you even have a `string?`, string is nullable to begin with.

Comment: @pikzen: The `T?` is shorthand for `Nullable<T>`, which has a [struct type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you want `null` if it is a reference type and `0` if it is a number or similar value type. You can simply use the `default` keyword to get such a value from `T`. Also, you might want to add the `this` keyword to the first argument so that it can be used as an extension method.

```
private T getValue<T>(this IEnumerable<Extension> extension, string attributeName)  
{  
    Extension ext = extension.SingleOrDefault(e => e.attributeName == attributeName);

    if (ext != null)
        return (T)ext.Attribute;
    else
        return default(T);
}
```

Comment: If you need custom default value for value types you still can use something like this (note that "**byte?**"):

    retVal.byteValue= getValueFromExtension<byte?>(u, "ByteToGet") ?? 42;  But in such case it makes more sense to pass default value to getValue method as one more argument

Comment: @SergGr: Very nice, didn't think of that. I could only think of adding another overload for this method.

Comment: StackOverflow is awesome, every answer here helped me, and it took about 5 minutes to get a complete answer. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

`T?` is indicative of a `Nullable<T>`, which is something that is limited to structs. A string is not a struct, and therefore is not appropriate to use in a method accepting or returning `T?`.

Unfortunately, if you *want* to return `null` for value types as well as classes (such as string), then you would not be able to support that with a single generic method. You would need to do as Allon suggests and return `default(T)`, which would *not* be null for (non-`Nullable<T>`) structs, or define two methods *with different signatures*, one for structs, and one for classes.

```
private T getValueForClass<T>(IEnumerable<Extension> extension, string attributeName) 
     where T : class 

private T? getValueForStruct<T>(IEnumerable<Extension> extension, string attributeName) 
     where T : struct 

...

var theByte = getValueForStruct<byte>(extensions, "ByteToGet") ?? 0; 
var theString = getValueForClass<string>(extensions, "Text") ?? "";
```

Comment: Your answer is good, I can only accept one of these as the answer, so I accepted the other which is what I'm actually using.

Comment: @user788402, that's good! Always accept the one must useful to you. Coin flips are also acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a nullable string.  The type parameter of Nullable is constrained to be a value type, and String is a reference type.  Your getValue method returns a nullable T- you'd need to constrain it to structs, and use a different method for classes:

```
//Return null if the extension doesn't have the value, returns the value if it does.
private T? getValue<T>(IEnumerable<Extension> extension, string attributeName) where T : struct
{
    IEnumerable<Extension> ext = extension.Where(e => e.attributeName == attributeName);
    if (ext.Count() > 0)
    {
        return (T)ext.First().Attribute;
    }
    return null;
}

//Return null if the extension doesn't have the value, returns the value if it does.
private T getValueObject<T>(IEnumerable<Extension> extension, string attributeName) where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<Extension> ext = extension.Where(e => e.attributeName == attributeName);
    if (ext.Count() > 0)
    {
        return (T)ext.First().Attribute;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then

```
//This works:
getValue<Byte>(u, "ByteToGet") ?? 0;

//This also works:
getValueObject<String>(u, "Text") ?? String.Empty;
```